# Не удаляется элемент в списке по индексу

Tags: python

```py
def take_var():
    print('Введите количество людей в круге')
    n = input()
    return n

count = int(take_var())

def mass(count):
    humans = []

    while count >= 1:
        humans.append (count)
        count -= 1

    humans.reverse()

    print(humans)

    while len(humans) >= 1:
        del humans[2]
        if len(humans) < 3:
            del humans[1]

    print (humans)



mass(count)
```

Comment: Приведи пример входных данных и того, что должно быть на выходе. Ну и разверни вопрос. У меня элемент по индексу удаляется. Точно такой же питон 

Comment: В круге стоят N человек (рис.). Они пронумерованы от 1 до N. Поочередно из круга начинает выходить каждый третий человек. Это продолжается до тех пор, пока в круге не останется последний человек. Определить его номер.

Например, если в круге стояло 7 человек, то его поочерёдно покинут 3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 1. Оставшимся будет человек, стоявший на 4 месте.

Comment: В этом коде круг покидает человек на третьем месте humans[2], в потом следующий за ним (4), а потом следующий за ним (5), пока не останется 3 человека. Не проверял, но так выглядит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По условию задачи вам нужно удалять каждого третьего. А вы каждый раз удаляете третьего от начала. Это разные вещи.

Правильный код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
count = int(input('Введите количество людей в круге: '))

humans = list(range(1, count+1))

print(humans)

cur_idx = 0

while len(humans) > 1:
    del_idx = (cur_idx + 2) % len(humans)
    del humans[del_idx]
    print(humans)
    cur_idx = del_idx
```

Comment: Мне кажется доп переменная тут не нужна `while len(a) > 1:  i = (i+2) % len(a) ; del a[i]`